# Android SQLite Database delete method, why return something > 0?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm currently learning [Notepad Exercise 1](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) on Google, here is the code about SQLite part:

> ```
> /**
>  * Delete the note with the given rowId
>  * 
>  * @param rowId id of note to delete
>  * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
>  */
> ```
>
> //mDb is instance of DatabaseHelper with getWritableDatabase()
>
> public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {
>
> ```
>         return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
>     }
> ```

Seems that they didn't mention why it's "> 0" at the end, could explain to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the  [docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String[]))

The number of rows affected if a whereClause is passed in, 0 otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the whereClause.

If you don't get at least 1, then it didn't delete it so it returns false otherwise returns true.